# Port Knocking with Mono On Linux

Tags: c#, monodevelop

I'm developing Port Knocking application with MonoDevelop on Linux.
Server application uses iptables to open/close certain port with command:

```
iptables -A INPUT -j DROP
```

it's successfully applying certain rules such as:

```
iptables -A INPUT -p udp --dport 606:610 -j LOG
```

then I created client application with UdpClient to send knocking request

```
private static UdpClient udp;

public static void sendmessage (string message, string host, short port)
        {
            try 
            {
                IPAddress ip=IPAddress.Parse(host);
                if(udp==null)
                    udp=new UdpClient();

                byte[]  b=ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes(message);
            udp.Send(b,b.Length,new IPEndPoint(ip,port));               
        } 

        catch (Exception exc) 
        {
            throw exc;
        }
    }
```

But this client app crashes, seems it's raising Exception when server closed every ports.

Is there any solution for sending data packet, that doesn't care whether server is closing/opening certain port?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try setting timeout low and ignoring the exception instead of throwing it